# Comparing objects of java.lang.Class and javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement

Tags: java, class, annotations

I wrote an annotation accepting a `java.lang.Class` object. I want to save the annotated classes and the annotation value as key-value pairs in a file, but in my case, this is only valid if the annotation value class is assignable from the annotated class.

Now in my annotation processor I got a `java.lang.Class` object from the annotation value and a `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement` as the annotated class.

As `java.lang.Class` only accepts a `java.lang.Class` for its `isAssignableFrom` method i don't know how to compare them that way.
I also couldn't find a proper method from `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement`.

My code is like so:

```
Set<? extends Element> annotatedClasses = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(DefaultOf.class);
for(clazz : annotatedClasses) {
    TypeElement asType = (TypeElement) clazz;
    Class<?> annotationVal = asType.getAnnotation(DefaultOf.class).value();
    if(annotationVal.isAssignableFrom((asType)) { // not working, wrong type
    }
}
```

How may I compare them?

Comment: See further discussion and answer in my [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77211537), which solves this problem along with the added wrinkle of generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

not tested but I'm using similar code:

```
Set<?extends Element> annotatedClasses = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(DefaultOf.class);
for(Element clazz : annotatedClasses){
  TypeElement asType=(TypeElement)clazz;
  Class<?> annotationVal=asType.getAnnotation(DefaultOf.class).value();
  TypeMirror annotationValType = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(annotationVal.getCanonicalName()).asType();
  if(processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(annotationValType, asType.asType())){
    //annotationVal class is assignable to annotated class
  }
}
```

basically you need to get type (`TypeMirror`) of your `annotationVal` class and then compare it by using `isAssignable` method from `TypeUtils`