# Java annotation processor comparing method return `TypeMirror` with known class

Tags: java, annotation-processing

My Java annotation processor is generating an implementation of an interface, which has a `MyInterface.foo()` method returning `CompletableFuture<String>`. In my processor the `ExecutableElement` for that method indicates a `getReturnType()` `TypeMirror` with a `toString()` value of `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<java.lang.String>`, so I know I have the right `TypeMirror` for the return type.

Now I want to test in code whether this `TypeMirror` instance is indeed a `CompletableFuture` of some sort. I tried `Types.isAssignable(…)`, `Types.isSubtype(…)`, and `Types.isSameType(…)`, but none seem to work. For example:

```java
TypeElement completableFutureTypeElement = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
    .getTypeElement(CompletableFuture.class.getCanonicalName());
boolean isCompletableFutureReturnType = processingEnv.getTypeUtils()
    .isSubtype(returnTypeMirror, completableFutureTypeElement.asType());
```

Am I using the wrong method for checking? Or is the problem that the return type is `CompletableFuture<String>` and I'm comparing against the raw type? In any case, how do I simply check to see that non-parameterized (i.e. raw) class of return type is `CompletableFuture`? I suppose I could just compare strings, but is there are more type-safe, semantic way?

My related question is how to get a `TypeMirror` for a known class, as I did above for `completableFutureTypeElement` and then `completableFutureTypeElement.asType()`. Is there a more direct way to get a `TypeElement` and/or `TypeMirror` for a class such as `CompletableFuture.class` without doing a lookup on the string form of its name?

Comment: See also a [related question[(https://stackoverflow.com/q/20358039) which addresses this problem but without the complication of a generic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the comparison technique in the question doesn't work because it compares the raw type to the actual parameterized type. If I cast the return `TypeMirror` to a `DeclaredType`, get its `Element` representation, and then convert back to a `TypeMirror`, then the comparison works—I suppose because I'm in effect applying erasure to the returned type:

```java
TypeElement completableFutureTypeElement = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
    .getTypeElement(CompletableFuture.class.getCanonicalName());
boolean isCompletableFutureReturnType = processingEnv.getTypeUtils()
    .isSubtype(((DeclaredType)returnTypeMirror).asElement().asType(),
        completableFutureTypeElement.asType());
```

That's seems to be a bit of a hack, though. Calling `processingEnv.getTypeUtils().erasure(returnTypeMirror)` on the return type mirror, which sounds like it would do the same thing, doesn't work, though. Moreover with this approach I can't seem to use `isSubtype(…)` or `isAssignable(…)` with `Future`, even though `CompletableFuture` implements `Future`.

Instead, the more semantic way seems to go in the other direction: **start by creating a `TypeMirror` for a parameterized `CompletableFuture<?>` against which to compare**—as you would do in Java code. You can create a parameterized unbounded wildcard using `Types.getDeclaredType(…)` from the `TypeElement` already created; along with `Types.getWildcard(…)`, passing `null` to indicate no `extends` or `super` bounds (i.e. the `?` wildcard). Then you use `isAssignable(…)` to see if the return type is something that can be assigned to the parameterized type you constructed.

```java
TypeElement completableFutureTypeElement = processingEnv.getElementUtils()
    .getTypeElement(CompletableFuture.class.getCanonicalName());
DeclaredType completableFutureWildcardTypeElement =
    processingEnv.getTypeUtils().getDeclaredType(completableFutureTypeElement,
        processingEnv.getTypeUtils().getWildcardType(null, null));
boolean isCompletableFutureReturnType = processingEnv.getTypeUtils()
    .isAssignable(returnTypeMirror, completableFutureWildcardTypeElement);
```

As a bonus, `isAssignable(…)` with a return type of `CompletableFuture<String>` will work against `Future<?>` as well, so that's a good indication that this second approach of creating parameterized unbounded wildcard types is the more semantic technique.